# How do I use an added jQuery script in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to use a read-more jQuery script on my wordpress website. The script I want to use can be found on https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js. I've used several stackExchange topics and the following tutorial http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/. But I still don't have it working. What have I done?

1. Created a folder in the theme directory called "custom_js". In this folder I copied the script called "readmore.js".
2. Added the following piece of code on the top of the functions.php file located in the theme directory:

   ```
   //this goes in functions.php near the top
   function my_scripts_method() {
   // register your script location, dependencies and version
   wp_register_script('custom_script',
   get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom_js/read_more.js',
   array('jquery'),
   '1.0' );
   // enqueue the script
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
   }
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
   ```

   The code in the readmore.js file is surrounded by this code:

   ```
   ;(function($) {
   })(jQuery);
   ```

Did I implement the script the right way? If no, then what did I do wrong? And if I did implement the script the right way, how do I call the script so there will be a read-more button on my wordpresspage?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine apart from how you wrap the readmore.js code. You need to wrap it like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    /* You can safely use $ in this code block to reference jQuery */
    // readmorejs contents here.
});
```

as opposed to

```
;(function($) {
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks. I assumed it was a synonym for jQuery(function ($). I've edited the readmore.js file but when I use ?$('Dit is de follow up').readmore(); in my wordpress editor is still does not work. Any ideas how to implement the JS script so it will be working on my live wordpress site?

Comment: `$('Dit is de follow up')` should be a reference to an `element` with your long text. So in your template you would have a block of say `<article>Lots of text</article>` and the you would call `$('article').readmore();`

Comment: It still is not working. I've answered srBlond her question with the following steps. Help is appriciated

Comment: Outside of wordpress it is *this* simple http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/Tv96A/ However I have now seen the code of readmore.js and it *is* originally wrapped in those tags you mentioned so you just need to wrap the whole thing in the function I mentioned.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker In both example the `$` variable is a safe reference to the `jQuery` variable. However, your example using `jQuery(someFunction)` is a synonym of `$(document).ready(someFunction)` and it's the unique difference with it's original code: in your case, the function execution gets delayed until the page load event, which sounds better in his case because he don't know where the script is injected and so the code need to be runt only when the article is loaded in the DOM.

Comment: I've made one example myself also in JSfiddle and it worked well. This is what I pasted in the HTML code <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
$('article').readmore();
    });
</script>. However, when I paste this in the WP editor it wont work. So maybe jQeury is not loaded the right way. Any suggestions? I've tried everything from the guide

Comment: This is the piece of code I use to call jQuery in the functions.php file which is located in the theme directory of my wordpress website: function my_init() {
 if (!is_admin()) {
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.3.2', true);
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

  // load a JS file from my theme: js/theme.js
  wp_enqueue_script('my_script', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/theme.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
 }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init'); which is also from the guide

Comment: Wordpress editor doesn't allow certain tags.  Have a look at custom_js plugin and then you can add that code in a separate field at the bottom of the post editor.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the plugin source it applies to `article` tag, so make sure your posts are wrapped in that tag.

Or you can change it from `$('article').readmore();` to `$('whatever article wrapper').readmore();`, for example `$('div.post').readmore();`.

Also make sure that script is loaded and loaded after jQuery.

Comment: @rob Schmuecker Ok, thanks. I've added a piece of text surrounded by <article></article> tags. After this piece of text I added this code: <script type="text/javascript" >
 jquery('This text should show up').readmore();
</script> Unfortunaly it's still not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here's how you should use it:

`$('article').readmore({moreLink: '<a href="#">This text should show up</a>', maxHeight: 100});`

outside wordpress works as planned.

Comment: @SjoerdPaardekooper 1. altering original WP jQuery with the earlier version may cause a lot of headache in the future. 2. Readmore plugin uses jQuery version 1.8.3, so I won't recommend you using earlier version. 3. Why don't you place your piece of script in a separate file? I am sure you'll need it in the future.